# Add Django ForeignKey as drop down selection on admin page

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to create a model `TestCase` which has a `products` field which is a ForeignKey to antoher model `Product`. I want to be able to create a new `Product` using the Admin page and then when I create a `TestCase` I want to be able to select from `Product`s I have already created. A dropbox would be ideal. This is what I have tried:

models.py

```
class TestCase(TestBase):

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Product(models.Model):
    products = models.ForeignKey(TestCase, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

admin.py

```
class ProductInline(admin.TabularInline):

    model = Product


class TestCaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    inlines = [ProductInline]

admin.site.register(TestCase, TestCaseAdmin)
```

Adding a new `TestCase` on the admin page now has fields to create a Product but I want to select from already created `Products` instead?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can a Product belong to more than one TestCase?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong model structure. If you want to be able to choose from a list of already-existing Products in your TestCase, and a Product can belong to multiple TestCases, you need a ManyToManyField which lives on TestCase.